# How to get the latest record from each group in ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

In my Ruby on Rails application I have a database structure like this:

```
Project.create(:group => "1", :date => "2014-01-01")
Project.create(:group => "1", :date => "2014-01-02")
Project.create(:group => "1", :date => "2014-01-03")

Project.create(:group => "2", :date => "2014-01-01")
Project.create(:group => "2", :date => "2014-01-02")
Project.create(:group => "2", :date => "2014-01-03")

# and so forth...
```

How can I get the latest record from each `group` using ActiveRecord?

The solution is probably simple but I can't get my head around this.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Do you want them to be sorted by their `date` field or by the time the records where created?

Comment: @Agis: By their `date` field.

Comment: In case anyone else arrives at this page just looking for how to sort by latest record on a single column (no grouping), just do something like ``Project.order(created_at: :desc).first``.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

#### Postgres

In Postgres, this can be achieved with the following query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON ("group") * FROM projects
ORDER BY "group", date DESC, id DESC
```

Because the `date` column might not be unique here, I have added an additional `ORDER BY` clause on `id DESC` to break ties in favor of the record with the higher ID, in case two records in a group have the same date. You might instead want to use another column like the date/time of the last update or so, that depends on your use case.

Moving on, ActiveRecord unfortunately has no API for `DISTINCT ON`, but we can still use plain SQL with `select`:

```
Project.select('DISTINCT ON ("group") *').order(:group, date: :desc, id: :desc)
```

or if you prefer using ARel instead of having raw SQL:

```
p = Project.arel_table
Project.find_by_sql(
  p.project(p[Arel.star])
   .distinct_on(p[:group])
   .order(p[:group], p[:date].desc, p[:id].desc)
)
```

#### MySQL

For other databases like MySQL this is unfortunately not as convenient. There are a variety of solutions available, see for example [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1313293/192702).

Comment: @p11y This is exactly what I was looking for as well, however, it doesn't work in PostgreSQL. I get a PGError - `column "projects.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`. Any ideas?

Comment: For **PostgresSQL** you may use `Project.select("DISTINCT ON(group_id) *").order("group_id, date DESC")`

Comment: Does'nt this only work if all the latest record have the same date value?

Comment: @Alain It does. I think the better solution is somethink like this: `Project.group("group").maximum(:date)`. It should return the max date for each group without omitting any group.

Comment: @Alain @qarol which query are you talking about? Both in mine and @remo's queries the `max` should apply only within a group.

Comment: @qarol you should make that comment an answer - it's actually the best solution (IMO)

Comment: @PatrickOscity I tried out `having` but it just returns the record with the latest date from the array returned by `group`. `group` returns an array of the first record from each group.

Comment: @carlmyerflor (and others before you) you're absolutely right, my bad. I remember I originally tried this out but overlooked that the maximum date is the same for all groups in the test data from the OP. Therefore my original approach _appeared_ to work but it doesn't. With Postgres, `DISTINCT ON` is definitely the way to go as @remo suggested. In MySQL and other DBs this is unfortunately more complicated to achieve. Editing my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 13):

I spent some time battling this and thought I'd share what I found to be the cleanest and stunningly easy solution (assuming `date` or other sorting field contains unique values):

```
Project.group(:group).maximum(:date)
```

Hat tip to [qarol](https://stackoverflow.com/users/580166/qarol) for posting this in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21289319/how-to-get-the-latest-record-from-each-group-in-activerecord/63348824#comment56573108_21289909).

Comment: It is definitely simple, but question was "How can I get the latest record". If user needs to extend this answer to include other fields, it's a problem.

Answer (score 7):

This works for me

```
ids = Message.select("MAX(id) AS id").group(:column_name).collect(&:id)
@result = Message.order("created_at DESC").where(:id => ids)
```

Comment: Be careful with this solution. If DB returns more than ~1'000 ids, this could lead to very long duration query.

Answer (score 5):

Following solution based on [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7745635/86047) works for MySQL and it's extensible to all fields in *group* table.

```
Project.select(:group, 'MAX(date) AS date').group(:group)
```

Comment: This. Works flawlessly and very fast.

Answer (score -6):

Something like this?

```
Project.select(:group).map(&:group).uniq.each do |grp|
  puts Project.where(group: grp).order("date DESC").last
end
```

This will go through all your groups and identify the unique ones. In your example it should return ["1", "2"]. Then it iterates over that array and selects the last Project with a group id of 1 and the last Project with a group id of 2.

** Update **

Just realized you said "latest" and not "last" which required adding an order to ensure latest works. Last still pulls just one.

Comment: this will also retrieve *all records* from the database, then filter them in memory and finally make another query for each group.

Answer (score -11):

```
Project.where(:group => "1", :date => "2014-01-01").last
```

.last is what you are looking for.

Comment: OK, thanks. And what if I don't want to specify the `group` and get the latest entries from *all* groups?

Comment: Just remove the where condition.

Comment: This does neither provide a generic way to find the latest one in a group, nor does it return all latest projects.

Comment: This will only return the last value regardless of the grouping