# Rails: select maximum date of each month

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

In my app users save a report each Friday for an organization. All my records in the reports table hold organization_id, day and workdays.

I want to get the sum of all workdays at the **last Friday** of each month.

With the following line I am able to select all reports for organization #8 and sum workdays **for each Friday**:

```
@all_report_sums = Report.where(:organization_id => 8).group(:day).select("day, SUM(workdays) AS sum_workdays")
```

**The result**:

```
[{"id":null,"day":"2017-02-03","sum_workdays":3},{"id":null,"day":"2017-02-24","sum_workdays":33},{"id":null,"day":"2017-04-07","sum_workdays":12}]
```

However in my output I only want the maximum dates of each month (which is the last Friday of each month) - so in my case this would be 2017-02-24 and 2017-04-07.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

This is what are you looking for

[How to get the latest record from each group in ActiveRecord?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21289319/how-to-get-the-latest-record-from-each-group-in-activerecord)

```
User.group(:user_id).having('day = MAX(day)')
```

Comment: Unfortunately not. This gives me only the reports with maximum date for each user (so literally 1 report per year per user). What I want is for each user FOR EACH MONTH the latest report. So, literally, I want for each user 12 reports per year (maximum in Jan, Feb, Mar etc.).

Comment: `User.group([:user_id, :day.beginning_of_month]).having('day = MAX(day)')`

Comment: undefined method `beginning_of_month' for :day:Symbol

Comment: `User.group_by{|e| [e.user_id, e.day.beginning_of_month]}.having('day = MAX(day)')`

Comment: undefined method `having' for #<Hash:0x007f9a957edcb8>

Comment: `User.select(:user_id, "date_trunc('month', day) as month", :value).group(:user_id, :month).having('day = MAX(day)')`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137491/discussion-between-tsao-and-oliver).

Comment: I rephrased my question, maybe its better from this starting point.