# Select highest ID from group

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm trying to group a table (`oauth_access_tokens`) by `application_id` and select the highest record by ID from the corresponding group (see the complete model below). I've seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21289319/how-to-get-the-latest-record-from-each-group-in-activerecord), which explains how to get the highest ID from the group, but sadly it's not working for my case.

I have a table called `oauth_access_tokens` with the following attributes: `id`, `resource_owner_id`, `application_id`, `token`, `refresh_token`, `expires_in`, `scopes` and `revoked_at`.

The method I have in my model:

```
def last_token
  Doorkeeper::AccessToken.group(:application_id).having('id = MAX(id)')
end
```

After calling it like so: `User.first.last_token` (I made sure that there are a few records in the database present).

[image]

**sql output:**

```
Doorkeeper::AccessToken Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `oauth_access_tokens`.* FROM `oauth_access_tokens` GROUP BY `oauth_access_tokens`.`application_id` HAVING id = MAX(id)
```

**Output:** `#<ActiveRecord::Relation []>`

Why don't I get the record with the highest ID? When I run `User.first.last_token` I expect to see the `access_token` with the `id` of 28.

Happy holidays!

Answer (score 0):

Given that `id` is the primary key of `:users` table and `oauth_access_tokens.resource_owner_id` points to `users.id`, something like this should work:

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  ...
  def last_token
    # 'id' (or, self.id) in 'resource_owner_id: id' points to the user id, i.e. 'User.first.id' in 'User.first.last_token'
    Doorkeeper::AccessToken.group(:application_id).where(resource_owner_id: id).pluck('max(id)').first
  end
  ...
end
```

---

Though the above solution should work, but you can improve the query writing to a more readable way by defining the associations inside corresponding models like below:

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  ...
  has_many :access_tokens,
    class_name: 'Doorkeeper::AccessToken',
    foreign_key: :resource_owner_id
  ...
  def last_token
    access_tokens.group(:application_id).pluck('max(id)').first
  end
  ...
end

class Doorkeeper::AccessToken < ApplicationRecord
  ...
  self.table_name = 'oauth_access_tokens'
  belongs_to :resource_owner, class_name: 'User'
  ...
end
```

In both cases, `User.first.last_token` will return `28` as you would expect.

---

#### Update

You are only 1 query away to get the access_token instances instead of mere ids. The method will now return an `ActiveRecord::Relation` of `Doorkeeper::AccessToken` instances which meet the defined criteria.

```rb
def last_tokens # pluralized method name
  token_ids = access_tokens.group(:application_id).pluck('max(id)')
  Doorkeeper::AccessToken.where(id: token_ids)
end
```

Comment: Hi Wasif, thanks for your response. I like your second example, all tho I would like to return the object for each group where the `resource_owner_id` == `User.id`. So imagine I have 2 groups that go by the application_id: 2 and one by application_id: 3 with both the same resource_owner_id. I would like to return the `access_token` object in that case for ID 2 and 3.

Comment: `oauth_tokens.group(:application_id).pluck('MAX(id)')` works, it gives me the correct ids back like I wanted as I mentioned above. Now I just have to figure out how to return the whole object instead of the ID only, that will save me from some unnecessary db queries, thanks Wasif!

Comment: Please check the updated section in the answer. Thanks